# Reading advertising packet data from a Movesense sensor

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ads, movesense

Please help, I am trying to decipher this advertising packet data on the Movesense sensor.

Somewhere in this next lines of data I have to find accelerometer data and heartrate date.

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

```
9/28/2021, 11:05:23 AMnode: e8e9a966.328e18
msg : Object
object
peripheral: "0c8cdc3872e8"
address: "0c:8c:dc:38:72:e8"
rssi: -75
connectable: true
name: "Movesense 204730000081"
manufacturerData: buffer[19]
[0 … 9]
0: 0x9f
1: 0x0
2: 255
3: 0xd4
4: 0xd
5: 0x0
6: 0x0
7: 0xed
8: 0x24
9: 0x4
[10 … 18]
10: 0x3c
11: 0x0
12: 0x0
13: 0x0
14: 0x0
15: 0x45
16: 0x95
17: 0x88
18: 0x3c
services: array[1]
0: "fe06"
_msgid: "cdbbd743.5fdd88"
```

Comment: Why do you think the acceleration and heart rate is in the advertisement? Do you have any documentation?

Comment: The code that writes the advertising can be found here....(https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/defd199c4121e9f659f66a9707f5fcdb9264e1be/samples/activity_broadcast_app/ActivityBroadcaster.cpp?at=wip%2Ftimppis%2Factivity-broadcast-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/defd199c4121e9f659f66a9707f5fcdb9264e1be/samples/activity_broadcast_app/ActivityBroadcaster.cpp?at=wip%2Ftimppis%2Factivity-broadcast-app) you provided byte 7-10 contain an incremented counter, byte 11-14 the accelerometer and 15-18 the average heart rate data.The last two are stored as float.

The accelerometer data is 0 so I assume you did not move the sensor.

The average heart rate contains the value 4595883c in hex (0x45, 0x95, 0x88, 0x3c). This needs to be converted to a float using little endian byte order. Using an [online converter](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) you can get the value 0.01667274. Since this is almost 0 I would assume that you did not measure anything.

You can now check the changing of the values by actually measuring the heart rate and/or moving the sensor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Michael. The Accelerometer data seems to work fine, but I cant seem to decipher the HR data. In actual fact the "HR" data seems to move with the accelerometer data when you shake it. We will keep in playing around.

Comment: Hi @michael Kotzjan, just a update. Thank you for your help. we managed to read it now.

Comment: @statspro1 glad to hear! If you discovered something I missed in my post feel free to add it here. Maybe someone else stumbles across this problem in the future

Comment: Thanks, no, what you said covered it. I see you are quite a BLE expert. Do you know of a way to increase a devices range? This sensor is supposed support Bluetooth 5.0 with its Nordic Semiconductor nRF52832 chip. I have not gotten more than 40meters range.

Comment: @statspro1 you might not be able to do that. 40m is already pretty good for a BLE device. The signal stregth depends also on factors such as the antenna used. You are right, BLE 5.0 offers an option for long range operation, but it is an optional feature that needs to be supported by the sensor and your phone to work. Maybe you can ask a new question and get some more answers